# Seeking guidance on debuging Django/mod_wsgi/apache performance

Tags: python, django, apache, postgresql, mod-wsgi

I've inherited a Django application currently hosted in docker/EC2 (python 3.6) running nginx/gunicorn with Postgres RDS. It's reasonably simple application whose big demand is to generate a very large template that is then spit out as a pdf report. The current production app takes about 1 to 2 minutes to render and download the file (about 1 MB).

I've been looking to migrate the application into Beanstalk. Things going well except performance. Same code takes about 2x to 3x to render. Been trying to figure out how to bring them into line and what the diff is.

New beanstalk environment is running the same instance size. Differences are:

1. Python 3.4 vs production 3.6
2. Apache/mod_wsgi vs nginx/gunicorn.

My suspicion is that I haven't configured apache correctly (followed https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/).

I haven't instrumented the code yet so don't have proof of where the time is spent but that's what I'm thinking.

This is obviously wage but wondering about guidance on tuning beanstalk/django application on apache/mod_wsgi and what I might consider looking into first.

Can provide any details required. Just not sure what's helpful.

Comment: Side note, python/django is not my sweet spot so naive solutions are very much on the table.

Comment: Since this is a CPU intensive task, an issue would be how many concurrent requests you get. The default process/threads model in Apache/mod_wsgi would rely on threads, but multiple CPU intensive tasks when relying on threading can impact performance because of the GIL. The default in gunicorn would be multi process and single thread in each process, so concurrent requests wouldn't cause an issue. If you are seeing slow down with only a single request, the machine size is likely to be issue if is different.

Comment: One can change how Apache/mod_wsgi is configured to use a multi process vs threads configuration, but need to see what you are using to start with.  So are you using mod_wsgi embedded mode or daemon mode. If daemon mode, how do you have ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` configured.

Comment: BTW, if someone jumps in and says nginx will make things quicker don't believe them, it will not in this case make any difference, it is going to come down to processes vs threads in the WSGI server used, and the machine size you are using.

Comment: Thanks. This site is really an internal site that sees almost no load. The new beanstalk configuration is in daemon mode. So we're really talking about comparing performance of a single request in both environment under no load. Right now, the code is designed to return an HTTPResponse with the file loaded into memory. I believe most of the time difference is in how the two web servers return such a response and how they perform. Going to test out writing the file to disk and letting apache handle the file download. I suspect that will improve thing immensely. Will write back with results.